# Different datas for each element inside vue-for cycle

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and since my start some week ago I find myself really happy about it and the way it can be combined with pure javascript. 
I'm running this code inside a laravel blade template:

```
  <template v-for = "background in backgrounds" >

                <template v-if="currentBackground.path ===  background.path">
                    <div class="m-1 background inline-block rounded-circle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden">
                        <img class="img-fluid " :src="background.path" v-on:click="changeBack(background)" :style="circledPositionStyle" v-on:load="inquadraThumb(background)">
                    </div>


                </template>
            </template>
```

And in the script section:

```
data() {            return {
                [...]
                frontObjects : '',
                circledPositionStyle : ''    }},
      methods: {
                      [...],
            inquadraThumb(back) {


                var thumbHeight = 100;
                var calculatedThumbPositionY = (back.Ypos * thumbHeight) / 500;
                var calculatedThumbPositionX = (back.Xpos * calculatedThumbPositionY) / back.Ypos;

                this.circledPositionStyle = "transform: scale(4); height: " + thumbHeight + "px;transform-origin:" + calculatedThumbPositionX + "px " + calculatedThumbPositionY + "px;";
            },
```

Now, the code works just fine, but all the images generated in the loop have the same `circledPositionStyle`style applied... How can I manage to have different values for each cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing `circlePositionStyle` as the data property, so if that value changes, it will change for every item that refers to it.

Instead, change your function to return the value of `curclePositionStyle` instead of mutating the data property.

```
inquadraThumb(back) {


            var thumbHeight = 100;
            var calculatedThumbPositionY = (back.Ypos * thumbHeight) / 500;
            var calculatedThumbPositionX = (back.Xpos * calculatedThumbPositionY) / back.Ypos;

            return "transform: scale(4); height: " + thumbHeight + "px;transform-origin:" + calculatedThumbPositionX + "px " + calculatedThumbPositionY + "px;";
        }
```

You will also need to slightly adjust the tag:

```
<img class="img-fluid " :src="background.path" v-on:click="changeBack(background)" :style="inquadraThumb(background)">
```

Comment: Yeah. Thank you, you saved me a lot of time